# from n text files to list of n objects in r

Tags: r, list, csv, txt

i have a folder "prod" containing several text files:

```
prod_123456.txt
prod_123474.txt
prod_1234567543.txt etc...
```

in each of them there is a list of objects (without commas) as follows:

prod_123456.txt contains

```
1213423
1245
12345
2321
134135
```

prod_123474.txt contains:

```
23425364
3245
123425367485
```

etc.

i want to read all of the files in the folder prod in a way such that they are stored in a list of lists object as follows:

```
[[1]]  123456
             
[1] 1213423
[2] 1245
[3] 12345
[4] 2321 
[5] 134135

[[2]]  123474
             
[1] 23425364
[2] 3245
[3] 123425367485
```

etc.

so basically, a list of n elements corresponding to n txt files where the code in the txt file name is the element itself, and for each element there s a list of the objects contained in the txt file

this is what i have so far

```
filenames <- list.files("folder/", pattern="prod", full.names=TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, function(i){
  read.csv(i, header=FALSE)
})
```

but it s a list of dataframes and there is no name of the corresponding files in the elements of the list

Comment: What you have tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vector filenames and read it with `readLines`.

```
filenames <- list.files('path/of/folder', full.names = TRUE, pattern = '\\.txt$')
list_of_vector <- sapply(filenames, readLines, simplify = FALSE)
```

if you want each element to be a list itself we can `as.list` in the function.

```
list_of_list <- sapply(filenames, function(x) 
                       as.list(readLines(x)), simplify = FALSE)
```

Using `sapply` with `simplify = FALSE` allows us to create a named list.

If we want names to be only numbers from filenames and not the complete path we can use :

```
names(list_of_vector) <- sub('.*prod_(.*)\\.txt', '\\1', filenames)
```

Comment: it works, the only problem is that the name of the elements is the entire directory to the file "path/of/folder/prod_1234" rather than "1234"

Comment: We can select the relevant part of path using regex. See updated answer.